# Bash monitoring jPos XML log file

Tags: xml, bash, jpos

I need to monitor log file which is produced by `jPos`. The log output looks like:

```
<log realm="channel/10.10.23.81:18090" at="2015-02-08 00:00:19.540 CET" lifespan="9019ms">
  <receive>
    <isomsg direction="incoming">
      <!-- org.jpos.iso.packager.GenericPackager[cfg/iso93ascii.xml] -->
      <field id="0" value="1804"/>
      <field id="7" value="20150208000019"/>
      <field id="11" value="399335"/>
      <field id="24" value="831"/>
    </isomsg>
  </receive>
</log>
<log realm="channel/10.10.23.81:18090" at="2015-02-08 00:00:19.540 CET">
  <send>
    <isomsg direction="outgoing">
      <!-- org.jpos.iso.packager.GenericPackager[cfg/iso93ascii.xml] -->
      <field id="0" value="1814"/>
      <field id="7" value="20150208000019"/>
      <field id="11" value="399335"/>
      <field id="24" value="831"/>
      <field id="39" value="800"/>
    </isomsg>
  </send>
</log>
```

One message is always between log tags and could be long many lines. Also could contains errors like:

```
<log realm="channel/10.10.23.81:18090" at="2015-02-06 00:01:58.728 CET" lifespan="26768ms">
  <receive>
    <iso-exception>
      org.jpos.iso.IFA_LLNUM: Problem unpacking field 56 (org.jpos.iso.ISOException: Field length 37 too long. Max: 35) unpacking field=56, consumed=282
      org.jpos.iso.ISOException: org.jpos.iso.IFA_LLNUM: Problem unpacking field 56 (org.jpos.iso.ISOException: Field length 37 too long. Max: 35) unpacking field=56, consumed=282
        at org.jpos.iso.ISOBasePackager.unpack(ISOBasePackager.java:265)
        at org.jpos.iso.ISOMsg.unpack(ISOMsg.java:420)
        at org.jpos.iso.BaseChannel.unpack(BaseChannel.java:924)
        at org.jpos.iso.BaseChannel.receive(BaseChannel.java:692)
        at org.jpos.q2.iso.ChannelAdaptor$Receiver.run(ChannelAdaptor.java:319)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
    </iso-exception>
    --- data ---
    0000  31 34 32 31 46 36 37 34  30 35 43 35 30 45 45 30  1421F67405C50EE0
0010  41 31 30 30 30 30 30 30  30 30 30 32 30 34 30 30  A100000000010330
0020  30 30 30 30 31 36 2A 2A  2A 2A 2A 2A 2A 2A 2A 2A  000045**********
0030  2A 2A 33 34 34 32 30 30  30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30  **35670000000000
0040  30 30 30 31 38 30 30 30  30 30 30 30 30 30 30 31  0001800000000001
  </receive>
</log>
```

I would like to `grep` whole one message by specific time stamp ("2015-02-06 16:") and string (like ORA, iso-exception, ...) and get nice output line-by-line (as the origin look). The `jPos` log file is huge, I try set monitoring for any malfunction and the result want send to email, so should be readable.

Any idea guys?

Answer (score 1):

I find out the solution. Merge the output using `perl`, `grep` the variables and format again to xml through `tiny`:

```
log_file=/path/q2.log
log_hour="2015-02-06 10"
file_to_send=/path/email.txt
tidy_temp=/tmp/tidy.temp

perl -pe 's|\n|| ; s|</log>|</log>\n|' $log_file |grep $log_hour |grep -e "ORA-" -e "iso-exception"| tidy -f $tidy_temp -o $file_to_send -i -xml -
```